# Can MongoDB user creation be automated?

Tags: mongodb, bash

I am considering using a local MongoDB instance to store data for an application. The user can't be expected to manage MongoDB themselves, so I need to be able to automate the installation and initial setup of MongoDB.

**Installation is easy enough, but how can one *automatically* create a User dedicated to the application?**

Let's say my application would connect using the following URI template or similar:

`mongodb://{usr}:{pwd}@{host}:{port}/{db_name}`

Is there a **non-interactive** way to create a user and password? For testing purposes, a Bash solution is fine for now.

Answer (score 1):

Reading https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/create-users/

Something like that could work:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

newUserName='usr'
newUserPass='pwd'
dataBaseName='db_name'

mongosh --port 27017  --authenticationDatabase \
    "admin" -u "myUserAdmin" -p "mySecretAdminPassword" <<EOF
use reporting
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "$newUserName",
    pwd: "$newUserPass",
    roles: [
       { role: "readWrite", db: "$dataBaseName" }
    ]
  }
)
EOF
```

Comment: I'm getting a connection refused error, probably because I don't know what the admin username and password are. It seems like the necessity of admin credentials poses a problem if someone were to install this application on a computer already running MongoDB, and maybe MongoDB isn't a good tool for this sort of deployment.

Comment: I think this only works when you already have the "admin" database with a user "myUserAdmin" in place, see [Use SCRAM to Authenticate Clients](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/configure-scram-client-authentication/) in the MongoDB Manual.